# MAMP OS X and CakePHP setup Server Error

Tags: php, apache, macos, cakephp, mamp

Just installed MAMP on OSX, and when I navigate to any of my cake apps that I have made on windows, I get a Server Error,

```
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost:8888/myApp. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
```

I am not using the native root folder, I am using `/public/sites`

I am not having a problem viewing normal php pages on my localhost, the problem only seems to exist when trying to view a cake app. It seems like a similar error to the mod rewrite not being enabled on wamp but i checked the httpd.conf file and it seems fine in `MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf`.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so is not commented out.
```

Thank you

Comment: Check the server's error log. And if PHP's configured to log to a file, check that as well (and/or turn on `display_errors` in php.ini).

Comment: Awesome, I checked the php error log and it directed me to the cake core folder being pointed to the wrong path in app/webroot/index.php. I have some other errors to work out now but this is what I was looking for if you want to put it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: It's not really an answer. Just a "start checking there" advice. For some reason a lot of people come here first before looking in the obvious places. Handy for racking up points here, but doesn't really help them to learn how to do it themselves.

Comment: i kept checking the apache error log because i thought for sure it was an apache issue... sometimes it just takes a fresh mind to help out also.

Comment: For the most part, I've never found Apache to be a problem with my sites. The PHP log is the first place I go. Apache's sensitive enough that it'll scream on any error conditions, while PHP will cover up as much as it can.

Comment: Did you copy all of the .htaccess files as well?

Comment: @jimiyash, yes I got that one figured out with a terminal command that allowed me to see all of my hidden files, that caused a little hiccup at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to app/webroot/index.php and changed the webroot path from windows location to the new osx path.

Answer (score 2):

Add `Options +FollowSymLinks` to your root .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```